# Should I calculate hash of endoded file (Base64) or should I decode it first?

Tags: java, hash, base64, decode, sha256

I have a question related to calculating hash. I have a program that receive a Base64 encoded file and I want to send that file to other program but checking the integrity. I will calculate de hash before send the file so I can send both and the other program will check the integrity.

Is there any difference between calculating hash of the encoded file and decode it first? Is there a best practice? I don't know if I should decode the file first and calculate hash of decoded one.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending it through a channel that doesn't have any consistency checks of its own?

Answer (score 1):

This is very vague and primarily opinion; but if "other program" can receive the binary contents without base64 encoding I would decode before taking the hash. A base64 encoded payload is 33-37% larger than the decoded payload, so that's an instant (minimum) 33% reduction in network traffic to "other program".

Comment: Another argument for hashing the decoded version is that the user probably does not care whether any corruption of the file was caused by the underlying channel or a bug in the encoding/decoding code. That is transparent to the user, an implementation detail of the transfer channel they probably don't even need to know about. And if the hash is displayed somewhere, the user could verify it using independent tools.